# How to create a process in C++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, process, multiprocessing

I'd like to create a process by calling a executable, just as `popen` would allow. But I don't want to actually communicate through a pipe with it: I want to control it, like sending signals there or find out if the process is running, wait for it to finish after sending `SIGINT` and so on, just like `multiprocessing` in Python works. Like this:

```
pid_t A = create_process('foo');
pid_t B = create_process('bar');

join(B); // wait for B to return
send_signal(A, SIGINT);
```

What's the proper way to go?

Use case for example:

- monitoring a bunch of processes (like restarting them when they crash)

**UPDATE**

I see in which direction the answers are going: `fork()`. Then I'd like to modify my use case: I'd like to create a class which takes a string in the constructor and is specified as follows: When an object is instantiated, a (sub)process is started (and controlled by the instance of the class), when the destructor is called, the process gets the terminate signal and the destructor returns as soon as the process returned.

Use case now: In a boost state chart, start a process when a state is entered, and send termination when the state has been left. I guess, http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.start_child is the thing that comes closest to what I'm looking for, excpet that it seems outdated.

Isn't that possible in a non-invasive way? Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding and there is a better way to do this kind of work, if so I'd be glad to get some hints.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to the answers below, I think I got the idea a little bit. I thought, this example would print "This is main" three times, once for the "parent", and once for each `fork()` – but that's wrong. So: Thank you for the patient answers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <unistd.h>

struct myclass
{
    pid_t the_pid;
    myclass(std::string the_call)
    {
        the_pid = fork();
        if(the_pid == 0)
        {
            execl(the_call.c_str(), NULL);
        }
    }
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::cout << "This is main" << std::endl;
    myclass("trivial_process");
    myclass("trivial_process");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the previously posted code, try this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class MyProc
{
public:
  MyProc( const std::string& cmd)
  {
    m_pid = fork()
    if (pid == 0) {
      execl(cmd.c_str(), cmd.c_str(), NULL);
    }
  }

  ~MyProc()
  {
    // Just for the case, we have 0, we do not want to kill ourself
    if( m_pid > 0 )
    {
      kill(m_pid, SIGKILL);
      wait(m_pid);
    }
  }
private:
  pid_t m_pid;
}
```

The downside I see on this example will be, you can not be sure, the process has finished (and probably he will not) if the signal is emitted, since the OS will continue after the kill immediately and the other process may get it delayed.
To ensure this, you may use ps ... with a grep to the pid, this should work then.

Edit: I have added the wait, which cames up in a comment up there!

Comment: Thank you, perfect! This is what I was looking for. You all mentioned it, but I did not see how to apply correctly.

Comment: Please don't use this code without adding additional code dealing with errors and reporting them to the caller. E.g. fork() and especially exec*() can fail.
 
I hate software telling me: 

"We are very sorry! Something did not work!"

Answer (score 3):

The below is not a realistic code at all, but it gives you some idea.

```
pid_t pid = fork()
if (pid == 0) {
  // this is child process
  execl("foo", "foo", NULL);
}
// continue your code in the main process.
```

Comment: I see in which directions the answers are going. Therefore I modify the question now to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Hm, suppose I wanted to re-write the bash. Would I use `fork()` to create a process? A shell does I/O, so `popen`. But it kills and suspends and knows about PIDs as well ... I don't get it :)

Comment: bash does indeed use fork(). In order to implement the redirection (that's the closest thing I can map to your popen reference)bash uses `dup`or `dup2` to copy the file descriptors around

Comment: In your constructor, you use the code fragment I specified, except the process is specified as absolute file path to the executable. The pid is saved in member variable. In the destructor, use `kill`function to kill the process and `wait` function to verify it exited and obtain the exit code.

Comment: Ah, I think, a fundamental misunderstanding was to believe, `fork()` was like restarting the complete process! So if `main()` prints something, I thoungt, if I use such a class, it's printed for every object.

Comment: fork simply continues the execution of your code, but it continues in TWO processes!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to `fork()` (`man 2 fork`)

Comment: Id did, but after `fork`ing, how would I go on? Set a string containing the executable's name, then `fork()`, change the string, `fork()` again?

Comment: Sounds like a hell of `if`s and `else`s, especially when I want to control say 10 processes. But thank you pointing me to the article.

Comment: you need fork, then exec in the child process