# How to access input and output stream of system() terminal/process in C

Tags: c, terminal

I am using the `system()` command in c, calling the su command, which requires the root password.

How do I provide that root password from the c program, instead of writing it manually in myself and how do I use the resulting root terminal ?

Comment: "provide that root password from the c program" --> If possible, hope one does not code the SU password in the clear.  Still, sounds like you want the ability for anyone to run the program as if SU.  Does not that defeat the whole reason for the password?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Agreed!

Comment: I am writing a mitigation for a vulnerability, it is all complicated, but what is clear is that this is part of a demonstration, for my uni unit, not something I would actually use. Can you answer the question pls, I want system() function to run su, recieve a password, without the requirement of the user actually typing it in and then run something as root.

Comment: _... run su, recieve a password, without the requirement of the user actually typing it ..._ you can, but that is a very serious security hole and I don't think your teacher wants you to do that, consider using `setuid`, if that doesn't convince you, you can also make sure the program is invoked by root by calling it from a [bash script](https://github.com/davranfor/linux/blob/main/commands#L411), anything but using the root password from a string literal.

Comment: I want to call the password from a string literal, well, no, It will be an int array, encoded, decoded during program run. Anyay. Sorry but none of the answers are helping, I want to provide the password for su running in a process in the c language, linux specific implementation if possible

Answer (score 2):

> How do I provide that root password from the c program

```
system("echo password | sudo -S program");
```

But providing the password in plain is a security hole as it can be easily extracted with tools like `strings` or `hexdump`, instead, setup the permissions:

```
sudo chown root myprogram
sudo chmod ug+s myprogram
```

and use `setuid(0)`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    setuid(0);
    system("./program_with_root_perms");
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by @Darth-CodeX, prefer the `exec` family functions over `system`, see how to combine `exec<whatever>` and `setuid`: https://0xdf.gitlab.io/2022/05/31/setuid-rabbithole.html

Comment: Is using `system()` good, why not use `create_process`?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX oops I didn't know `create_process`, is this `win32` stuff?

Comment: yeah, but unix/linux based **os**es have something similar to `create_process` which is *https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305605/17939455*

Comment: Darth-CodeX means the family of `exec...` calls, which are available on Windows, too.

Comment: @thebusybee yeah, I also prefer this approach, edited.

Comment: @thebusybee these functions are available for windows under `cygwin` layer, as `cygwin` uses POSIX libs

Comment: ok, Thanks. I will try this, Will mark it as the answer if succesfull.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX MinGW has them, too. And Microsoft C has them, even if prepended by an underscore.

Comment: @thebusybee MSYS2 and MinGW are based on cygwin, so yeah they have it too. But I didn't get `"Microsoft C"` you mean `msvc`?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Yes, Microsoft's C++ and C runtime.

Comment: The problem is, is that users won't have access to the sudo command, I really need to c program itself to authenticate su and run something as root.